# What's the limit on multiple keyword searches using App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

Trying to do multiple keyword search on google using App script, wanted a bit information on what's the limit for number of searches we can do using app script, I know that google API has 100/day limit for free.

Was there any higher limit for using app script as its a google's own feature?
Tried to find in documentation, no mention of appscript+API on searches limits